# Как реализовать проверку на пробитие брони у танка

Tags: разработка-игр

Я собираюсь сделать свою игру про танки, наподобие всем известных World of Tanks, и т.д. У меня появилась проблема, которая заключается в том, что я не знаю как можно реализовать проверку на пробитие. **Каким образом можно получить угол, под которым попал снаряд, толщину брони именно в этом месте. Но самое главное наверное то, как просчитать это всё при условии что броня может быть полукругом.** Думаю над этим уже довольно давно, буду рад, если вы предложите свои идеи для реализации. Можете использовать примеры из любых удобных для вас движков.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что значит "не важен движок"? От движка-то все и зависит. В Unity это можно сделать так, в каком-нибудь 3DRad это уже не прокатит.

Comment: Имею ввиду то, что вы можете использовать пример из любого движка на любом языке. Мне важна сама система, по которой я смогу реализовать это.

Comment: Вот система-то и будет различаться. В разных движках по разному получаются и обрабатываются данные. В самых общих чертах — в обработчике событий коллизии определяете толщину, прочность и форму брони в этом месте. Дальнейшее зависит от движка.

Comment: Как делать математические расчеты — это уже от вас зависит (и от физической составляющей движка).

Comment: Самое больше меня сейчас интересует, как получить толщину и угол в месте столкновения. К примеру, возьмём Unity. Насколько я знаю, рейкастинг выдаёт только место, и объект, куда попал луч.

Comment: Наверняка это как-то решается навешиванием нескольких коллайдеров на танк. Разной "толщины", для "пробития" которых нужна разная мощность. А вот как дальше считать... Надо какие-то специальные форумы читать для игроделов.

Comment: "Каким образом можно получить угол" -- через скалярное произведение обратного вектора скорости снаряда и нормали к полигону в точке попадания.   "толщину брони именно в этом месте" -- можно разметить толщину брони в виде текстуры с одним каналом, привязанной к полигонам collision hull, и, соответственно, смотреть значение пикселя в нужной точке.

Comment: Считать толщину через тексель не самое точное решение, т.к. в зависимости от угла прилета, толщина будет от "Х" для перпендикулярного прилета, до "оченьмногоХ" для прилета по касательной. С другой стороны, это игра, и тут важнее не физический реализм, а условный "игровой". В первом приближении можно будет действительно делить "толщину по текселю" на косинус угла между нормалью и вектором прилета.